# Проблема с округлением значения item

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside2, qtablewidget, qtablewidgetitem

Имеется код:

```
def buttonLast(self):
    row = self.tableWidget_3.rowCount()
    if not row:
        return
    column = 1
    item = self.tableWidget_3.item(row - 1, column)
    print(round(item))
```

В котором выбирается последнее значение в столбце `tableWidget`.

Но, при команде `print(round(item))` получаю ошибку:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "G:\PyCharm\SckethPython\pythonProject_x32_3_8_6\SL_lke2.1.py", line 138, in buttonLast
>     print(round(item))
> TypeError: type QTableWidgetItem doesn't define __round__ method
> ```

Comment: У вас `item` явно не типа `float`, а, похоже, что `QTableWidgetItem`. Достаньте само значение оттуда (я не знаю QT, но похоже что надо сделать что-то вроде  `float(item.text())`) прежде чем округлять.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То к чему вы собираетесь применить `round` -  это `QTableWidgetItem object`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Example(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mytable = QTableWidget(4, 2)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.mytable) 
        btn = QPushButton("Click me")
        btn.clicked.connect(self.buttonLast)
        layout.addWidget(btn) 

        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(2):
                item = QTableWidgetItem("{}.{}123000".format(i, j))
                item.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
                self.mytable.setItem(i, j, item)

    def buttonLast(self):
        row = self.mytable.rowCount()
        if not row:
            return
        column = 1
        item = self.mytable.item(row - 1, column)
        print(f'\nitem --> {item}\n')     #  --> QTableWidgetItem object at 0x0...>
        if item:
            item = item.text()            #  --> str
            item = float(item)            #  --> float
            print(round(item))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]